# blinking cursor in textarea issue

Tags: javascript

We have created a js effect where users click buttons outside of a textarea, and the value of those buttons is displayed within a textarea.

The issue I have is, because the textarea does not have focus, then no cursor is displayed.

I wondered if there was a faux way of displaying a blinking cursor all the time in the textarea.

Comment: How users will interact with the UI? Are they expecting to enter text after clicking a button, or do they just click buttons to add text and not type anything?

Comment: Hey Rob, sorry for delay. They cannot type in the textarea, basically each time they press a button some text is added to the textarea, the more buttons they press forms a sentence, so would be nice to show blinking curor in textarea

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you could do is call `.focus()` on the text area when the button is pressed.

This has the added advantage of not confusing the user. If you just faked it, a user would expect to be able to type in the text area without clicking on it again.